# Jquery hide() should only be applied to visible elements

Tags: jquery, user-interface

```
$(".selector").hide("fold", 2000);
```

I want this code to hide only elements that are visible on the page, in other words, those that have the style display: block.

When I run this code on my page, it applies the effect also to the elements that are invisible. The elements that invisible should not be seen having that effect at all.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `:visible` selector

```
$(".selector:visible").hide("fold", 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`:visible` pseudoselector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```
$(".selector:visible").hide("fold", 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:visible` filter. However, note that `:visible` filter would consider elements that have `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0` as visible, because they still consume space in the page.